# flex-shrink based on length of each element

Tags: css, flexbox

Say I have the following path:

*Home / Folder 1 / Folder 2 very very long name / Folder 3 / Folder 4*

What I want to do is that flex-shrink each part of the path based on their length. For instance, I want to flex-shrink the "*Folder 2 very very long name*” by a factor that is proportional to its length.

I have attached an example jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/carinquiryad/utcp4x59/12/.

```
.single-breadcrumb-wrap {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
flex: 0 auto;
flex-shrink: 1000;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 5px 15px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
color: var(--main-color);
position: relative;
}
```

If you notice here, the last path is very long, and so some of the middle folders do not show up except for the "..." part. Please ignore the hover aspect, I am just interested in the base view at this point. As you can imagine, this is just an example, our actual content is dynamic and the various parts can each of arbitrary length.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this using CSS? Or if you know of any library that achieves that, please let me know.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: added jsfiddle as above

Comment: You could set `flex-shrink: 1;` on the shorter `.single-breadcrump-wrap` and `flex-shrink: 2;` on the longer. But you would probably need a little bit of javascript for it. (But maybe there is also a css only solution out there i dont know)

Comment: Thank you - these are  all dynamic and there could be many such "parts" of varying length. I could do something in JS but it would be be somewhat convoluted to handle all the cases. In any case, thank you.